# Sharing data using common ngModel in two different forms angular 5

Tags: html, typescript

I hav 2 forms. On the navigation bar , there are 2 buttons for navigating to form1 and form2. There are some common fields in the both forms. After filling some data in form1 if user navigates to form2, the common fields filled in form1 should appear on form2. And vice versa. 
So is there any way that i can keep the ngModels common for those fields. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please put some code? `html`, ts? Because it is hard to give you an answer without knowing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the class in providers and use dependency injection in both form components with the same instant name..

Answer (score 0):

> keep both forms in to same page, hide previous form at clicking first form button.

Comment: Can we create a base class which has the common properties and form1 and form2 component extend from it.. how will that work syntactically...please help

Answer (score 0):

> create common class like this

```js
export class Sample{
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

import other form component

```
import { Sample } from './sample'
```

and then use the variables